# How to use Selenium to verify Sorting of records

Tags: sorting, testing, selenium

I have a list of records. How I can verify the sorting order using Selenium?

```
List<WebElement> tableRowCollection = webTableElement .findElements(By.xpath("/table"));
```

I am getting an error in the above statement "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments ". I am not sure how to read the records since findElements only returns WebElemt.

Comment: You read the contents of the list on the page and compare it to a list of records in the expected order... What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using selenium IDE or something? Since there's no actual language tag.

Comment: I am using Selenium webdriver, I just updated my question with the code.

Comment: Make sure to import `import java.util.List` not the awt one

Comment: `WebElement` has a method `getText()`

Comment: I did that now I see this error "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebElement>"

Comment: Do you want me to try something like this? List<WebElement> tableRowCollection = webTableElement .findElements(By.xpath("/table")).getText();

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getText() is undefined for the type List<WebElement>
 - The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your imports, you most likely are not importing `java.util.List`

The following code will add the text of a whole row to the collection `elements`:

```
List<WebElement> tableRowCollection = webTableElement.findElements(By.xpath("/table"))
List<String> elements = new LinkedList<String>();
for (WebElement e : tableRowCollection) {
    elements.add(e.getText());
}
```

This should get you started, but I really recommend you to read some documentation related to Java collections.